# Replace using regular expression in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, sed

I need a regular expression to replace using sed in ubuntu.

From: "a,b,c"
To: ""
notes - within double quotes

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for formatting help and see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve on how to write a better question... you'll also have to show your efforts to solve this

Answer (score 0):

use `[^"]+` it will match any characters and stop before `"` found

```
echo '"a.b.c"' | sed -r 's/[^"]+//g'
# ""
```

Comment: thanks, but I need to remove any characters within double quotes. can you please rewrite it for me.

Comment: above regex is remove any chars and produce `""`